# Change fields in table under /models folders does not update table schema

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have trouble in changing fields in my database table. I rewrite them in `sequelize` definition model files like follows: [model that defines table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHKoW.png)

But when I **add** a column to this table, the **error** tells me I have to add a missing column attribute which I deleted before. I am pretty new to databases and ORM. Please give me some advice, thank you!!

[image]
migration file is also modified. And then I used command Sequelize db:migrate
Is there anything I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new too but I'd say you also have to reflect the changes in the migration file and then do a sequelize db:migrate to make them take effect in the database.

Comment: I did copy new fields in migration files. I don't know in what way to correlate two of them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error is come from elsewhere try to access the non-existed attributes, I tried to migrate my database using the command (sequelize db:migrate or npx sequlize-cli db:migrate) they did work, if the schema did not update. check if sync() is used. More info could be found here. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#extending--a-href-----class-lib-model-js-model-html--model--a-